# How to build an ionic app for operating systems other than android and ios

Tags: ionic-framework, operating-system, hybrid-mobile-app

I have built my ionic app and it is ready to run on android and ios, I need to support more OS's as arora or any existing mobile OS.

Answer (score 0):

you can build android , iOS (and  windows, and blackberry apps for ionic 2)